# Добавления евентов и атрибутов

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

К примеру есть Dropdown, у него есть атрибут Options, в который мы можем вписать строку (названия) и добавить спрайт, я почти на 100 уверен что это сделано с помощью списка (List<>), но как оформить это как в Dropdown[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

похожий вопрос меня интересует как можно добавить в свой скрипт евент (любой, кроме того что использовать EventSystem, т.к. он для всего объекта) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown рисуется (как и большинство юнитековских классов) через кастомный редактор для этого класса.

[DropdownEditor.cs](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/9f418c4767c47d0c71f1727eb42a9a9024e9ecc0/UnityEditor.UI/UI/DropdownEditor.cs?at=2018.2&fileviewer=file-view-default) - редактор для типа `Dropdown`, а уже внутри него для отрисовки листа опций используется [DropdownOptionListDrawer.cs](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/9f418c4767c47d0c71f1727eb42a9a9024e9ecc0/UnityEditor.UI/UI/PropertyDrawers/DropdownOptionListDrawer.cs?at=2018.2&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Вообще в репозитории с [исходниками UI системы](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src) много чего интересного и познавательного можно найти.

А чтобы сделать такое же событие в своём классе, как вы показали на скрине - вам нужно использовать юнитековский класс событий [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html). Просто объявите его публичным или сериализуемым в своём классе и кастомный рисовальщик от юнитеков сам его правильно нарисует.